# Best way to include/embed PDF images in slidify presentation (R Markdown)

Tags: html, r, pdf, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm preparing a presentation in .Rmd (R markdown) file using [slidify](http://slidify.org/).
I have some vector graphics saved as PDF files that I would like to render on particular slides.

I've tried methods that I used in raw .Rmd (markdown syntax) as well as  those from [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html). However, none of them works.

As I can see in generated HTML, PDF file location is directly provided in `img src` and as I understand HTML files do not directly support PDF files.

However, I'm not sure what to do (what is the best approach):

- convert PDF (to .svg) and use it in .Rmd?
- try to write some raw HTML in my .Rmd fo;e using suggestion from [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) that will allow me to render PDF,
- use different command to embed PDF in presentation (something specific to slidify)?